# Creating a parallax page and positioning elements within the sections

Tags: html, css, parallax, absolute

I am currently building a parallax page, but I have problems positioning the elements on the sections. Hence my problem is absolute positioning.

Is there any way to make the absolute position to work within a section only instead of the entire page/viewport?

I have made a very minimal example of what I am trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/zu2epxxq/1/

As you can see the paragraph within `#second` section should position inside of that section and not the main section `#first`. Obviously this is a side-effect of using absolute positioning. 
How do I solve this in a clean and good manner?

HTML:

```
<section id="first">
  <div>
    <p>This is a test</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="second">
  <div>
    <p>More text that has to be pushed arund in this section</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#first {
  background-color: #000;
}

#second {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

section > div {
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I didn't see any `position: relative` for `absolute` element. you may need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "position: relative;" on the sections. You then can position the child elements relative to the section elements.

I made this out of it:
https://jsfiddle.net/hpepwvdg/1/

But I prefer using the flexbox layout mode since I discovered the power of flexbox: (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp):

```css
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
      color: #fff;
}
.container {
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#first {
    background-color: #000;
}

#second {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.centered_heading {
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<section class="container" id="first">
  <h1 class="centered_heading">Centered!</h1>
</section>

<section class="container" id="second">
  <h1 class="centered_heading">Centered!</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Is there any benefits in using flex-box over the traditional methods i am using?

Comment: I just couldn't get it to work with your method. Don't know what I did wrong. From there I decided to make a code snippit with flexbox since I think it's easier. Flexbox is very powerful, the only problem is the IE support, it isn't that great at the moment. But even then, if you're into front-end web development I suggest you to take a look at this: [a-guide-to-flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I can use the same features from absolute positioning etc?

Comment: Yes you can, I  tried it again and made this out of it: https://jsfiddle.net/hpepwvdg/1/